# Google Admob for iOS. When and how will the real ads appear?

Tags: ios, admob, interstitial

Recently I added interstitial ads in my iOS App. Although during development phase we are supposed to use testDevice id for test ads. The google admob faq says that you can submit the app with the testDevice id code still in it. I did submit it with this.
Will my app serve real ads when its on the store??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. But you cannot check this with your own device, which was set in the testDevices.

For future reference here is the link which verifies this: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/targeting#faq

Answer (score 5):

It'll indeed serve live ads for all devices except those that you listed as testDevices.

Another thing that came to my mind *(isn't really related to your question but I think that you may benefit from the information anyway, if you don't know it already)* is that if you are building with the iOS 9 SDK then you must disable ATS as the current AdMob SDK is not compatible with ATS. If ATS isn't disabled it will prevent AdMob SDK from receiving and serving ads. You will find more information about this on Google's [Ads Developer Blog](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.se/2015/08/handling-app-transport-security-in-ios-9.html)

Comment: Thanks Markus for the answer. I have built the application using xcode 6 so that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with iOS10, you should add this to your .plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Otherwise only test ads will appear. You can find more details about it at [Firebase's Admob documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/app-transport-security).

Of course if you add your device to `testdevices` in the `GADRequest` it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have configured AdMob with the correct `app-id` and `ad-unit-id`. The installation instructions appear to use placeholder ids, not the ones for your instance.